# Django lazy load data of referenced object

Tags: django, foreign-keys, lazy-loading

I'm a total newbie to Django & Python!

I have the following class in models.py

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    useruniqueid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) #BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'myuser'
```

and another class with reference to MyUser

```
class MyCompany(models.Model):
    uniqueid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) #BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, db_column='useruniqueid')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'mycompany'
```

in my views.py i perform a query like this:

```
def companyDetails(request, id):
    property = MyCompany.objects.filter(uniqueid=id)
    output = serializers.serialize('json',property, fields=('uniqueid','name','country','city')
    return HttpResponse(output, content_type="application/json")
```

i want also to serialize the user fields like phone and nickname how can i do that, I read the  tutorial as well as https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/relations/ but i can;t figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The Django serializer is not that flexible to expand foreign keys. Also, once you serialize a queryset, it is no longer lazy-loaded. So I think the most flexible option would be to construct the JSON document yourself. For e.g:

```
import json

def companyDetails(request, id):
    json_doc = []
    for c in MyCompany.objects.filter(uniqueid=id):
        jobj = {}
        jobj['uniqueid'] = c.uniqueid
        jobj['name'] = c.name
        jobj['country'] = c.country
        jobj['city'] = c.city
        jobj['user'] = {"name": c.user.name, 
                        "nickname": c.user.nickname, 
                        "phonenumber": c.user.phonenumber}
        json_doc.append(jobj)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(json_doc, indent=2), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: if I have only one company and it has only one user(the CEO) why do i need to run in a loop?

Comment: Even if you have one company, `filter` will return a QuerySet and you will have to index the first element. Else you can use [`get`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) to get just one element and remove the loop.